# Velocity / Marketo issue with if statements that include a space

Tags: velocity, marketo

I am writing some Velocity Script as part of a Marketo email template that requires that I check if an boolean attribute on a lead is set or not.

When I attempt to display something associated with a lead in my system I can do something like;

`{{lead.myName}}`

This also works for fields that have spaces in them;

`{{lead.my name}}`

When it comes to using that field for `#set`ting or `#if`ing something then it doesn't work as well.

`#if($lead.my name)` throws an error saying that an unexpected space has been found.

I have tried variants like `#if(${lead.my name})` to no avail.

Any help / pointers would be massively helpful.

### Actual use case

In my example the field I need to access is called `lead.Subscribed to Innovation (L) 1`, I don't think the brackets will cause a problem, certainly any error messages have been space related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [User Guide](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#variables)  variables cannot have spaces

A VTL Identifier must start with an alphabetic character (a .. z or A .. Z). The rest of the characters are limited to the following types of characters:

```
    alphabetic (a .. z, A .. Z)
    numeric (0 .. 9)
    hyphen ("-")
    underscore ("_")
```

even with the curly brackets :
this is valid:

```
 #set( ${myemail} = "email@email.com" )
```

while trhis is invalid:

```
#set( ${my email} = "email@email.com" )
```

My best guess will be to change the source system to comply with the velocity naming convention.